# When does a selenium browser die automatically?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

We have created many test suites using selenium. They all ran successfully when we executed them individually. But when we try to run the whole suite, the browser dies at random timings and we receive the following error message.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'XXX-XXXX102', ip: 'XX.XX.XX.XXX', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver
Command duration or timeout: 22.04 seconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time: '2015-02-27 09:10:26'
System info: host: 'XXX-XXXX102', ip: 'XX.XX.XX.XXX', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=.//div[contains(@class,'dijitDialog') and @role='dialog' and contains(@style,'opacity: 1')]//input[@name='uploadedfiles[]' and @type='file']}
Session ID: e536c0bb-57a3-4d20-84e4-d3760ff9ddd3
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=false, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, webdriver.remote.sessionid=e536c0bb-57a3-4d20-84e4-d3760ff9ddd3, version=38.0.1, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'XXX-XXXX102', ip: 'XX.XX.XX.XXX', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time: '2015-02-27 09:10:26'
System info: host: 'XXX-XXXX102', ip: 'XX.XX.XX.XXX', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

As far as I know, there are no bugs in the code. Hence please let me know, under what conditions does the selenium grid kills the browser automatically.

Comment: Do you make https calls?

Answer (score 3):

`Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.` this error comes due to some reasons.

1) Accidentally browser get closed after some time or your grid machine will do the same.

2) `driver.close();` call before complete the executions.

- May be you write `driver.close();` in after class.

3) `driver.quite();` has also same problem as Point 2.

4) Please also check your driver instance initiate everywhere perfectly.